# How can I prevent TFS Integration service from polling a server that it is no longer migrating from?

Tags: tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

I have the TFS Integration tool running, performing a one-way migration (call it A) between a 2010 instance (call it X) and a 2013 instance (call it Y). This tool was also configured to do a one-way migration (call it B) from a different 2010 instance (call it Z) to Y.

Now I only need migration A, so I removed migration B. However, I now see in the logs every minute an entry like this (actual server name replaced in emphasized text):

> [10/22/2015 1:42:53 PM] TfsIntegrationJobService.exe Error: 0 :  [10/22/2015 1:42:53 PM] Sync Monitor Thread: SyncMonitor: ERROR: An unexpected error occurred polling migration source '**TFS instance Z** (VC)': Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException: Team Foundation services are not available from server **TFS instance Z**\DefaultCollection.
>   Technical information (for administrator):
>     HTTP code 503: Service Unavailable ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.AsyncWebRequest.ExecRequest(Object obj)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.ProcessHttpResponse(HttpWebResponse response, Stream responseStream, WebException webException, XmlReader& xmlResponseReader)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.ExecWebServiceRequest(HttpWebRequest request, XmlWriter requestXml, String methodName, HttpWebResponse& response)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Repository.QueryChangeset(Int32 changesetId, Boolean includeChanges, Boolean generateDownloadUrls, Boolean includeSourceRenames)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer.GetChangeset(Int32 changesetId, Boolean includeChanges, Boolean includeDownloadInfo, Boolean includeSourceRenames)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer.GetChangeset(Int32 changesetId, Boolean includeChanges, Boolean includeDownloadInfo)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.Tfs2010VCAdapter.TfsVCSyncMonitorProvider.GetSummaryOfChangesSince(String lastProcessedChangeItemId, List`1 filterStrings)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.Toolkit.SyncMonitor.Endpoint.Poll()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.Toolkit.SyncMonitor.MonitorWatcher.Worker()

The question is, how can I get it to stop polling instance Z? Restoring connectivity to that server is not an option. And letting it continue polling is not an option because it polls every minute and waits nearly a minute to time out - leaving basically no time to do anything else.

Comment: Did you try to restart TFS Integration Job Service? Does it work?

Comment: @Cece Yes I did, and bounced the server. And no, it still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete these configurations which are used to migrate Instance Z. On the TFS Integration -> Open Existing -> select that configuration and click Delete.

Or, you can create a fresh new configuration to migrate from Instance X to Instance Y.

Comment: I had already removed the migration that way. The problem is that even with it removed the tool seems to still be polling the old instance.

Comment: Does that configuration exist on your local machine? How about you create a new configuration file?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "exist". It is no longer in the list of configurations when I go to _Open Existing_, but I can still find traces of it in the DB. If I create a new configuration file, what would I put in it? Do you mean just delete migration A and recreate it?